Why is "hard of hearing" an idiomatic phrase, but "hard of reading" isn't commonly used?
"Hard of hearing" is a widely recognized and standard phrase in English to describe someone with hearing difficulties. On the other hand, "hard of reading," though grammatically correct, is rarely used and sounds unusual to most English speakers. Is there a specific historical, cultural, or linguistic reason why "hard of hearing" became idiomatic while "hard of reading" did not? Are there similar examples of this pattern in English?
Is "hard of reading" actually grammatically correct?

What is “hard of reading” supposed to mean?

hard of hearing means there is something wrong with your hearing apparatus. When you can't see properly, you have a problem with your eyes. There is no idiom hard of seeing.

Related question, almost a duplicate here

The question confuses seeing and reading, which is not the only purpose of the eyes. One idiom for "hard of seeing" is "eyes are dim", or "sight is dim".

It would have been grammatical in the 17th century.  Foods that were difficult to digest were "hard of digestion" and things that seemed impossible were "hard of belief" when someone asserted that they had happened.

Expressions 'hard of [noun]' are rare in the English language, and thus, as the grammar is unusual, idioms: one can't assume that substituting 'hearing' with any other noun (including nounal ing-forms), even one that looks logically similar/appropriate, will give an acceptable expression.
The meanings of those expressions that are idiomatic (commonly used and thus acceptable) defy a uniform analysis. Below is a list of some 'hard of [noun]' expressions:

hard of heart [common, often in Christian commentaries] (cold, unsympathetic; hard-hearted)
hard of understanding (deliberately obtuse, though UrbanDictionary offers other senses, including stupid, and at least one example on the internet obviously means 'hard to understand')
hard of thinking {adjective; modelled on hard of hearing} [humorous, derogatory] (having difficulty in thinking; stupid) [Wiktionary]
hard of seeing {adjective; formed by analogy of hard of hearing (having reduced ability to see) [Wiktionary]
hard of eye and grim of jaw [Word Reference forum] {literary} (looking stern; compare hard-faced)

Other candidates are best avoided, and I wouldn't use hard of understanding, hard of thinking or hard of seeing either. Wiktionary  lists no 'hard of [noun]' phrases beyond those given here. As stated, these expressions are extragrammatical (not ungrammatical), which means that licence is granted for those candidates that are in common use ... but not others.
.............
It is rare that a satisfactory answer can be found for questions like 'Why is idiom I restricted to nouns N₁, N₂, N₃  ... in the noun slot?' Idioms are idiosyncratic; etymologies are often sketchy and non-explanatory.

Really? The Urban Dictionary for that? Not worth the time.

Never shall it cease to amaze me how extraördinarily numerous are the Why?-type questions our site receives concerning matters which are inherently resistant to clear, discrete, and dispositive explanation! One might well ask ᴡʜʏ this recurring misconnect with linguistic reality by naïve askers keeps happening to us, a sort of meta question whose ᴏᴡɴ answer ᴏᴜɢʜᴛ not fall into the resistant category trap just described.

@Lambie 'There is no idiom hard of seeing.' But Wiktionary lists the expression. And even UD can be more use than opinionated people who don't bother checking: there is some evidence of how people (plural) use the language.

Both the Wikitionary one and the UD one are odd-men out. The question is where do you draw the line in language games?//The reason we get so many questions like this is because many people don't grasp what an idiom/idiomatic usage actually is.

@tchrist, while it is true that the origin of many idioms is lost in the mists of time, and that this renders unanswerable such questions about them, there are other idioms whose origin and features can be explained. It is not at all strange that a curious person would wonder whether a particular idiom is of the former or the latter kind, and come here to inquire about it. If it turns out that it is of the former, that is the answer, rather than a reason for disparaging the question. (Note that the OP is asking 'is there a . . . reason', not assuming that there must be.)

@Lambie 'Answers accompanied by references are usually preferred on ELU' is a quote I remember from years ago. Wiktionary is a sight better than an unsupported answer; there are those who post pronouncements as if they were gospel, apparently setting themselves up as a trustworthy authority.
